Find necessary and sufficient conditions for $A+I_n$ to be invertible, where $\operatorname{rank}(A)=1$.
Let $A \in\operatorname{Mat}(n\times n, \mathbb{R})$ and $\operatorname{rank}(A)=1$.
Prove $A^2=aA$ where $a=\operatorname{tr}(A)$.
From there, find the necessary and sufficient conditions for $A+I_n$ to be invertible and find $(A+I_n)^{-1}$ in terms of $a$.
My attempt:
Since $\operatorname{rank}(A)=1$, there're exists $U_{n\times 1}$ and $V_{n\times 1}$ such that $A=U.V^T$.
Since ${a_{ii}} = {u_i}{v_i} \Rightarrow a = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{a_{ii}}}  = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{u_i}{v_i}}  = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{v_i}{u_i}}  = {V^T}U.$
$$\Rightarrow A^2 = AA = U{V^T} \cdot U{V^T} = U({V^T} \cdot U){V^T} $$
$$= U \cdot a \cdot {V^T} = a \cdot U \cdot {V^T} = a\,A$$
To find the condition for $A+I_n$ to be invertible, I have seen many solutions using eigenvalues. But I didn't learn the basic properties of that particular value, so I couldn't apply it directly.
The problem wants me to use $A^2=aA$ to find the necessary and sufficient conditions for $A+I_n$ to be invertible. Could you guys suggest me a quick way to handle the rest?
Thank you.

Hint. Suppose $I+A$ is invertible and its inverse is in the form of $I-cA$ for some scalar $c$. Can you express $c$ in terms of $a$?

@user1551 thank you so much for your big hint. I found $c=\frac{1}{a+1}$ and now the problem is solved!

This shows that $A$ is invertible when $1+a\ne0$. You also need to show that $I+A$ is singular when $1+a=0$.

A sufficient condition is that $\| A\| \leq 1$.
In fact using sub moltiplicativity and you can easily prove that $\sum_n A^n$ converge absolutely. Since you are in Banach space this implies simple convergence, then $S=\sum_n A^n$ is well defined.
Then you can observe that $(id-A)\sum_n^k A^n=\sum_n^k A^n(id-A)$ for all $k$.
Moreover, taking limits, $(id-A)\sum_n^k A^n= id -T^{k+1} \to id$. This prove that (id-A) is left and right invertible with S as inverse.
These argument is independed from rank condition, maybe using these condition can be true also the inverse implication.
